Why is my CloudRun container not receiving traffic?
I'm trying to deploy an app on CloudRun and I always get an error about the container not starting because it failed to listen to the port 8080. I've tried everything I could think of, but nothing seems to work.
gcloud run deploy MyApp \
--image eu.gcr.io/MyProject/MyApp:latest \
--platform managed \
--memory 1G \
--cpu 1 \
--quiet \
--region europe-west1 \
--no-allow-unauthenticated \
--set-env-vars MAX_POOL_SIZE="10" \
--concurrency 10 \
--max-instances 2 \

Deploying container to Cloud Run service [MyApp] in project [MyProject] region [europe-west1]
Deploying...
Setting IAM Policy..............done
Creating Revision..........done
Routing traffic........................................................................................................................failed
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision 'MyApp-00072-xxx' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. 
The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. 


Here is what I get from the logs:
DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@5fb3855a

Container called exit(0).

Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container "MyApp-1" on port 8080. The instance was not started.

Ready condition status changed to False for Revision MyApp-00072-qav with message: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable.


The logs say your container is exiting, so the problem seems to be with your container and not with the Cloud Run deploy command. Have you tried running the container locally?

Your container called exit. That means the issue is with your application or how the container is starting the application. Review the application logs for the reason. If the logs do not have a reason, add logging to your code.

Please check this documentation on Cloud Run container failed to start error.
